# Dirac equation with an external Yang-Mills field

Tags: gauge-theory, fermions, dirac-equation, yang-mills

We know that the Dirac equation of a fermion coupled with a Yang-Mills field contains a term $i\gamma^{\mu}A_{\mu}\Psi$ describing this interaction (i.e. the interaction does not depend on the value of the Yang-Mills field $F_{\mu\nu}$ but on the value of $A_{\mu}$).

Let's consider now the case where $A_{\mu}=A^{(0)}_{\mu}$ satisfies
$$F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu}A^{(0)}_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A^{(0)}_{\mu}+[A^{(0)}_{\mu},A^{(0)}_{\nu}]=0.$$ This means that the Yang-Mills field vanishes, **but we have a non-trivial potential $A^{(0)}_{\mu}$ appearing in the Dirac equation through the term $i\gamma^{\mu}A^{(0)}_{\mu}\Psi$, describing a non-trivial interaction**.

What's going on in this case? Is there a true physical interaction between the fermion and the Yang-Mills field even when $F_{\mu\nu}=0$? If not, what's the procedure to remove the term $i\gamma^{\mu}A^{(0)}_{\mu}\Psi$ from the Dirac equation?